# Need Help adding programmatically adding ToggleButton to a FrameLayout with half the layout_weight

Tags: android, android-layout, android-layout-weight

My goal is to dynamically add a toggleButton to a frameLayout (which has it's own weight), but have the button be half the width of the frameLayout. I am able to create what I want in XML, but I'm having trouble trying to make this work programmatically.

Here's my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/columns"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="8">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/column_1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/background_dark" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/background_dark" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/background_dark" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/background_dark" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/background_dark" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/background_dark" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/background_dark" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/background_dark" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/background_dark" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/background_dark" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/background_dark" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/buttonLayoutWrapper"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:weightSum="2">

                <ToggleButton
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="360dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:checked="true"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textOff=""
                    android:textOn=""/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Please pay particular attention to the LinearLayout with the id: buttonLayoutWrapper and it's child ToggleButton as those are what I need to add dynamically. For simplicity sake I'm only showing one column, but would repeat this for 7 more.

I tried creating a separate class that Extends LinearLayout and adds the ToggleButton thinking that I could get the weight that way, but no luck.

No matter what I do, I can't seem to get the ToggleButton to obey the layout_weight.

Below is a sample of trying to do this programmatically:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.column_1);
    ToggleButton toggleButton = new ToggleButton(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutWrapper = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 360, .5f);
    toggleButton.setChecked(true);
    toggleButton.setText("");
    toggleButton.setTextOn("");
    toggleButton.setTextOff("");
    toggleButton.setLayoutParams(layoutWrapper);
    frameLayout.addView(toggleButton);
}
```

It seems that I need to have a parent LinearLayout that sets weightSum for the layout weight to work in the XML version. However, I can't seem to figure out how to add a LinearLayout parent to this that can then be added to the FrameLayout without getting a strange:

> cannot cast LinearLayout to FrameLayout

error when compiling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Rewrite**

Try the following. It adds the `ToggleButton` to the `LinearLayout` then adds the `LinearLayout` to the `FrameLayout`. I think it is what you are looking for. (Comment out the `LinearLayout` and `ToggleButton` in the XML so you can see this work.)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final float dpToPx = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        final FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameLP =
            new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                         FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        linearLayout.setLayoutParams(frameLP);
        linearLayout.setId(View.generateViewId()); // API 17+ needed
        linearLayout.setWeightSum(2.0f);

        final ToggleButton toggleButton = new ToggleButton(this);
        final LinearLayout.LayoutParams linearLP =
            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, (int) (360 * dpToPx), 1.0f);
        toggleButton.setLayoutParams(linearLP);
        toggleButton.setChecked(true);
        toggleButton.setText("");
        toggleButton.setTextOn("");
        toggleButton.setTextOff("");

        linearLayout.addView(toggleButton);
        final FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.column_1);
        frameLayout.addView(linearLayout);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Cheticamp.  Thanks for the response.  To be more clear.  The code example above works without error.  I get the casting error only when I try to wrap a linear layout around the code that is listed above (trying to mirror what I'm doing in the xml).  Additionally, I need the toggle button to be inside the FrameLayout so it will live above the background views.

Any code examples to do what I'm doing in xml would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: @BrianBegun After your comment and taking a closer look, I was able to update the answer.

Comment: that's exactly what I needed!  Works like a charm!  Thanks!  I'll mark it as answered.